# MacBook Pro only stays on for less than a minute

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, startup

This morning when I woke up my computer it turned off itself. Now it won't stay on for more than a couple minutes. The computer will boot up normally, but soon it turns off again. When it turns off, I hear a tiny clunk that I think is the hard drive, but I'm not entirely sure.

What can I do to troubleshoot the problem myself?

This is about a MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011.

Comment: Click the power indicator, what does it show?

Comment: Inspector Gadgets question: How can you hear a tiny clunk while driving in the car?

Comment: Please do not use a screwdriver!, Sometimes the battery is not locked in place, so vibrations could be in effect here. Make sure it is locked. When you say "Now it will not stay On" do you mean it is plugged in to the wall outlet?

Comment: @Borderline I heard the clunk when I tried it again at my desk. :)

Comment: @Robuust The computer will boot up normally, but if I bump it at all, even typing on the keyboard, it shuts down again. Edited question to include this.

Comment: @stephenwade Have you tried checking the hard disk with the disk utility programm in recovery mode? Or doesn't that work either?

Comment: @Robuust haven't tried that but I'm rather scared to try because I don't want to damage it by having it in use scanning when the thing shuts off.

Comment: Now that I'm home, I got the computer to stay on for a couple of enough to get off the 2 files I need most urgently. I have verified the problem happens both when on battery and when on wall power.

Comment: It's back from the dead! I took the computer apart to reseat the memory and battery cable, and since I had 16GB of RAM I was planning to install this weekend, I put that in as well. Now it's working beautifully!

Comment: Also, there was a tiny (pentalobe?) screw sitting on one of the memory chips when I took it out. I wonder if that had anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

It could be something as simple as you power button is stuck, forcing it to shut down.

If you hold the power button for 10 seconds it will forcefully shut down the computer.

In that case it will make the tiny clunk noise, which is normal due to HD been turned off and the HD reader head dropping. Do not do this to often, since you might damage it.

The stuck power button happens to computers on the back seat of the car exposed to food and other stuff.

If the hard drive is dead, you will see a gray screen, and that bad hard drive would not turn off the computer.

Comment: Mac can have Blue or Grey screen, Blue is the dead hard drive, grey is system did not load properly.

Comment: It's not a stuck power button. Sometimes it lasts until I log in, but then a tiny bump to the computer, even as small as typing on the keyboard, will kill it again.

Comment: Thanks for additional information. That helps narrowing it down. Now we can say it is not your hard drive and it is not your battery and it is not corrupt operating system. You said you get all the way till the log in screen ! But when you touch the keyboard to write your log in it shuts down ! I would recommend you take a look at the hard drive mount,= take it out than back in (ONLY when your computer is Off). If you have external keyboard plug it in and try with that.

Comment: Psst! did you spill coffe on the keyboard!

Comment: Also, just in case you have a bug or dead rive, try booting in safe mode : and it goes like this: To start up into Safe Mode (to Safe Boot), do this:

Be sure your Mac is shut down.
Press the power button.
Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold the Shift key. The Shift key should be held as soon as possible after the startup tone, but not before the tone.
Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple icon and the progress indicator (looks like a spinning gear).

Comment: No coffee spills! Also, the computer is back! I took the computer apart to reseat the memory and battery cable, and since I had 16GB of RAM I was planning to install this weekend, I put that in as well. Now it's working beautifully!

Comment: Also, there was a tiny (pentalobe?) screw sitting on one of the memory chips when I took it out. I wonder if that had anything to do with it?

Comment: First of all I am glad it is working again. hmm, the screw ? what else did you find in there :), no it should have not been there in first place, and it could have made the problem. I hope I was of help (at least i stuck with you till the end).